# php multi curl post a csv file

Tags: php, curl

I use  the following curl to multipart post contents of a csv file via curl to another server

I have 1500 records in the csv file and it takes around 5 minutes to  post the data ..

Is there a way we can make the post of each record faster .
Will  curl multi work here ?  or will it just end up posting same content multiple times .

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], __DIR__.'/uploads/'. $_FILES["image"]['name']);

$file = "uploads/payables.csv";
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer [some_token_key]";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.org/api/v1/imports.json");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [$authorization, 'Content-Type: text/csv']);
$cfile = new CurlFile($file,  'text/csv');
//curl file itself return the realpath with prefix of @
$data = array('data-binary' => $cfile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using curl_multi_*() is unlikely to help and is only going to be possible if you can shard the data *at both ends* of the exchange.

Since you've presented no analysis of where the bottleneck is, its impossible to say what will make this exchange go fast. Certainly its *unlikely* to be latency, but might be bandwidth, might be network configuration, might be capacity at either the client or the server, might be lots of other things or it might be a combination of factors.

You might consider trying to isolate the problem before you start trying to fix it.

If the issue is bandwidth (and some network configuration issues) then compressing the file should make a significant difference. Unfortunately, I don't think libcurl's option for enabling SSL compression is exposed in PHP - so you'd need to inject a transfer-encoding header and compress the file in your code. Compressing a file in PHP is easy, but only if you can load it all in memory. Compressing a stream is [a bit more involved](http://php.net/manual/en/filters.compression.php).